# Assigning bits to a 64-bit variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I am kinda new to bit operations. I am trying to store information in an int64_t variable like this:

```
int64_t u = 0;

for(i=0;i<44;i++)
   u |= 1 << i;

for(;i<64;i++)
   u |= 0 << i;

int t = __builtin_popcountl(u);
```

and what I intended with this was to store 44 1s in variable u and make sure that the remaining positions are all 0, so "t" returns 44. However, it always returns 64. With other variables, e.g. int32, it also fails. Why?

Comment: Although the second loop wouldn't cause any trouble (that is because it has no use at all), `u |= 0 << i;` wouldn't be the proper way to clear (set to zero) the `i`th bit. You should rather do something like `u &= ~(1 << i);` to clear the `i`th bit of `u`. `1 << i` would shift `1` to the left by `i`, then `~` would inverse the whole thing. `and`ing with that would clear the bit where `0` is, that would be the `i`th bit, where `1` was before the inversion.

Comment: In your second loop, anything `|` 0 is just the original value. I.e., `u |= 0 << i` leaves `u` completely unchanged regardless of the value of `i`.

Comment: In that case the first loop would do the trick by itself, no?

Comment: `u = (1u << 44) -1;` (you don't need the loops)

Comment: I need the loops because i'll iterate over a vector and assign the 1s accordingly.

Comment: BTW, you meant `u = (u << 44) - 1;`, right? It gives me 64 all the time;

Comment: @wildplasser, should be `u = (UINT64_C(1) << 44) -1;`, I guess.

Comment: No, IIRC you don't need to sizecast 1u or 1ul or 1ull constants. (maybe if they exceed native machine register size). `u = (1ull << 44) -1;` will do, anyway. @KeithThomson below has the correct answer.

Comment: If you want a vector with all the n low bits 1 then you don't need a loop either. Set the element at the border to `(1ULL << m) - 1` then set all the low elements to `~0` and all the high elements to 0.

Answer (score 4):

The type of an expression is generally determined by the expression itself, not by the context in which it appears.

Your variable `u` is of type `int64_t` (incidentally, `uint64_t` would be better since you're performing bitwise operations).

In this line:

```
u |= 1 << i;
```

since `1` is of type `int`, `1 << i` is also of type `int`.  If, as is typical, `int` is 32 bits, this has undefined behavior for larger values of `i`.

If you change this line to:

```
u |= (uint64_t)1 << i;
```

it should do what you want.

You could also change the `1` to `1ULL`. That gives it a type of `unsigned long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits but is not *necessarily* the same type as `uint64_t`.

Comment: Your suggestion gives me t=6;

Comment: @a3mlord: I get 44: https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/d7260611080f74fab130

Comment: @a3mlord: Argh! That was a typo, now corrected. Abject apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The way that is foreseen by the standard to produce the correct constants is `UINT64_C(1)`, I think.

Comment: No need for apologies, thanks for the help; BTW, I came up with: `uint64_t u = 0;
uint64_t b = 1;
for(i=0;i<44;i++){
u = u|b;
b = b<<1;
}
`

what would be the most efficient approach in terms of execution time?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt `UINT64_C` is in §7.20.4.1 1 "Macros for minimum-width integer constants", but it expands to `uint_least64_t`, not `uint64_t`.

Comment: @a3mlord: Or `... u |= b; b <<= 1; ...` The most efficient approach for what you're doing would be `uint64_t u = 0xfffffffffff;`. With the loop (which apparently is needed for what you're *really* doing), I doubt that the performance would differ significantly.

Comment: @chux, yes exactly that is a type that is at least 64 bit wide, so it can hold the 44 bits as required, here, to initialize an `uint64_t`.

Comment: @chux: I suspect that `UINT64_C()` is for `uint_least64_t` rather than `uint64_t` because the former is mandatory, while the latter is optional (a compiler might not support a type that's *exactly* 64 bits). Personally, I find the cast simpler and more readable.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Agree the using `(uint64_t)1` is preferable over `UINT64_C(1)`.  `UINT64_C(1)` may have side effects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451101/declaring-64-bit-variables-in-c/19453213#19453213

Answer (score 0):

1. __builtin_popcountl takes unsigned long as its paremeter, which is not always 64-bit integer. I personally use __builtin_popcountll, which takes long long. Looks like it's not the case for you
2. Integers have type 'int' by default, and by shifting int by anything greater or equal to 32 (to be precise, int's size in bits), you get undefined behavior. Correct usage: u |= 1LL << i; Here LL stands for long long.
3. Oring with zero does nothing. You can't just set bit to a particular value, you should either OR with mask (if you want to set some bits to 1s) or AND with mask's negation (if you want to set some bits to 0s), negation is done by tilda (~).

Comment: "Integers have type `int` by default".  That's not really correct. Integer *objects* have whatever type they're declared to have. Integer *expressions* have a type that depends on the expression; there is no default. The issue here is that the constant `1` has type `int`. The type of an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` in which its value can be represented. (In C90, the list was `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`; that changed in C99.)

Answer (score 0):

**When you shift in the high bit of the 32-bit integer and and convert to 64-bit the sign bit will extend through the upper 32 bits**; which you will then OR in setting all 64 bits, because **your literal '1' is a signed 32 bit int by default**. The shift will also not effect the upper 32 bits because the value is only 32 bit; however the conversion to 64-bit will when the the value being converted is negative.

This can be fixed by writing your first loop like this:

```
for(i=0;i<44;i++)
   u |= (int64_t)1 << i;
```

Moreover, this loop does nothing since ORing with 0 will not alter the value:

```
for(;i<64;i++)
   u |= 0 << i;
```