# How to make 64bit Preprocessor defined constant compile without warning?

Tags: c, macros

Imagine this:

```
#define PUTVALUE 0x000000000000000F
#define SetStr(s) literate(s)
#define literate(s) #s

...

foo (PUTVALUE, SetStr(PUTVALUE));
```

How can I make work this, where `foo` wants as first parameter a 64 bit integer, and as second parameter a const string with a hexadecimal representation of that integer with leading `0x`.

So I cant do:

```
#define PUTVALUE 0x000000000000000Full
```

as this would break the second parameter.

But not doing so is breaking the first.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you've shown? `0x0F` will be implicitly cast to a 64-bit int if you pass it to a function that expects one.

Comment: @interjay Because the function parameters are part of a variable argument list, and the types are just my internal rule. This is just the minimal example.

Comment: Do you want a constant or a macro?

Comment: Your question title says "constant", but I cannot see any constants, only macros. And your response to @interjay's comment indicates that the question is missing vital information.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with my Question? hm? I explained whats the problem in an unique way. And I also explained why it is neccsesary to specify it explicitly as a 64bit "macro".

Comment: The "function parameters are part of a variable argument list" and the post's "foo wants as first param a 64 bit integer" is a contradiction as variable argument lists are never the first parameter. @interjay point is correct in that a function expecting a 64-bit would perform an implicitly cast.    The post and self-answer  are good but need refinement.

Comment: @chux I also wrote that this is just to simplyfy my damn situation. ofc it isnt the first argument, in my case there are additional 3 strings before the varglist begins. but why should this interesting you?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I figgured just out an awesome way to do so:

```
foo (INT64_C(PUTVALUE), SetStr(PUTVALUE));
```

Is doing exactly that job.

Comment: Disagree about "doing _exactly_ that job".  `INT64_C()` expands an integer constant to type `int_least64_t`, not `int64_t`. To see how this may make a differece:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451101/declaring-64-bit-variables-in-c/19453213#19453213  A pedantic solution would use `((int64_t) INT64_C(PUTVALUE))`.  Further, as `0x000000000000000F` is unsigned, should not one use `UINT64_C()`?

Comment: @chux No, as ofc the define will cahnge in diferent versions, otherwise I would just write it in the code instead. and the point is. It IS not unsigned. it hast to have a sign whe the first bit gets set. But about the cast you are right. didn't know about that.