# How can I convert a binary number (32 bit) to a decimal number?

Tags: c, binary, ieee-754

I've seen various programs where I can convert a given decimal floating point number, to a binary in the IEEE 754 format.
Now, given a binary number, how can I get the program in C to convert it to a floating point number?

Example:

```
Input:  01000001010010000000000001111111
Output: 12.50012111663818359375
```

Comment: Mostly, we start by writing some code. Have you written any yet?

Comment: Are you sure about *decimal floating point number* and *binary in the IEEE 754 format*? Your input looks like a binary representation, possibly as a string, you could use `strtol` to parse it and the output may be the string conversion performed by `printf("%f", f)`, so you have some hints to start coding...

Comment: Hmmm This works for the title problem.  `01000001010010000000000001111111 binary` --> `1095237759 decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the binary representation as a `string`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void setBit(uint32_t* f, int i) {
    uint32_t mask = ((uint32_t)1) << i;
    *f |= mask;
}

float readFloat(const char* bits) {
    assert(strlen(bits)==8*sizeof(float));
    assert(sizeof(uint32_t)==sizeof(float));
    float f = 0;
    int size = strlen(bits);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int bit = bits[size-i-1]- 0x30;
        if (bit) {
            setBit((uint32_t*)&f, i);
        }
    }
    return f;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const char* bits = "01000001010010000000000001111111";
    float f = readFloat(bits);
    printf("%s -> %.20f", bits, f);
}
```

Gives

> 01000001010010000000000001111111 -> 12.50012111663818359375

Comment: Should you care about portability to 16-bit platforms (prevalent in embedded word in 2015), `uint32_t mask = 1u << i;` is a problem as `unsigned` may be only 16-bit.  Multiple ways to cope: `uint32_t mask = ((uint32_t)1) << i;` or `uint32_t mask = 1LU << i;` or `uint32_t mask = UINT32_C(1) << i;`.  I like the first.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19451101/2410359