# promoting integer to long or unsigned long

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

```
static uint32_t get_num(void);

uint32_t get_count(unsigned int mask)
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
  uint32_t count = 0;

  while (i < get_num())
  {
     if (mask & (1 << i++))
       count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

In this code, what would be more safe `(1L << i++)` or `(1UL << i++)` ?

Comment: `(1U << i++)` should be fine, because `mask` is also only an `unsigned int`. But you should take care that `i` will not be larger than 31.

Comment: What is the range of `get_num`?

Comment: Why make `i` a `uint8_t` ?

Comment: None. Programming with side effects in expressions is evil.

Comment: When using shifts - especially right shifts, best to use constants that are the exact same type as the result. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19453213/2410359

Comment: Agree with @chqrlie, just use `unsigned i = 0;`

Comment: See [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for better ways to count the bits set in an integer.

Comment: @chux: you mean especially left shift, don't you?

Comment: You should enable all warnings/errors on for your compiler. This will warn for instance about your usage of unsinged vs singed operators (e.g. `mask & 1<< ...`). Also, you might want to use a stdint type for mask, too (as you use it for the other vars already).

Comment: @chqrlie Yes - I agree with you.  Left shifts are important with signed/unsigned types.  Correctly sized right shifts are important with signed types.  In the end, using a matching type is best.

Comment: @chux: Right shifts should best be avoided with signed integers as the standard leaves explicitly open wether the shift is signed or unsigned. This is legally exploited by compilers as not all CPUs have signed right shift instructions.

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned operand is a bit safer because only then is the behavior of all the shifts defined when `get_num()` returns the number of bits in that operand's type.  If `unsigned long` is wider than `unsigned int` then `UL` is slightly safer than just `U`, but only for accommodating `get_num()` results that aren't valid anyway.

Safer yet, however, is this:

```
uint32_t get_count(uint32_t mask)
{
  uint8_t num = get_num();

  if (num == 0) return 0;

  /* mask off the bits we don't want to count */
  mask &= ~((uint32_t) 0) >> ((num < 32) ? (32 - num) : 0);

  /* count the remaining 1 bits in mask, leaving the result in mask */
  mask = (mask & 0x55555555) + ((mask & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1);
  mask = (mask & 0x33333333) + ((mask & 0xcccccccc) >> 2);
  mask = (mask & 0x0f0f0f0f) + ((mask & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4);
  mask = (mask & 0x00ff00ff) + ((mask & 0xff00ff00) >> 8);
  mask = (mask & 0x0000ffff) + ((mask & 0xffff0000) >> 16);

  return mask;
}
```

Comment: For using exact matching size type in the shift: +1. Better than `U`, `UL` or `L`, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid there are missing parentheses: `+` binds stronger than `>>`

Comment: The int-literals should be UL (L to get at least 32 bits, U as this is unsigned). Also I would limit the result, not mask in advance: remove line `mask &= ...` and change `return mask & ((1UL << num) - 1);` safes a conditional and some arithmetic ops. num should either have no stdtype (unsigned int) or one of the fast ones (let arch choose the best).

Comment: unsigned long (`UL` for literals) is at least 32 bits, so yes, it is safe to use! If it is 64bits, the compiler can (and will) optimize it to all 32 bits.

Comment: @Olaf, the hex literals do not need either U or L.  A hex literal's value is always unsigned, and a signed or unsigned type is chosen automatically for it that is sufficiently wide to accommodate its value.  `mask will be promoted, if necessary, for the bitwise `&` operations and sums, but this is value-preserving, and the result can safely be assigned back to `mask` without modification or loss.

Comment: @Olaf, the decimal literals (and the octal literals) even less need either `U` or `L`.  Nothing in the way any of them are used risks undefined behavior, nor can it produce results different from the intended ones.

Comment: Didin't talk bout the hexlits (allthough `UL` would give the compiler a hint which may help reporting invalid usage), but the 32 (the width-adjustment line). These will give conversion warnings (if enabled which should be) as being signed by default. Regarding risks: not for this one, but is is good practice in general and once getting used to avoids to forget it in critical situations. Called defensive programming and should be used expecially in weak-typed languages like C (in other words: use all help from the tools you can get). Anyway; not worth the discussion

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the 1-bits in an uint and use gcc, you should have a look at the builtin functions (here: `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`). These can be expected to be highly optimized and even use special instructions of the CPU where available. (one could very wenn test for gcc).

However, not sure what `get_num()` would yield - it just seems not to depend on `mask`, so its output can be used to limit the result of popcount.

The following uses a loop and might be faster than a parallel-add tree on some architectures (one should profile both versions if timing is essential).

```
unsigned popcount(uint32_t value, unsigned width)
{
    unsigned cnt = 0;   // actual size intentionally by arch

    if ( width < 32 )
        value &= (1UL << width) - 1;  // limit to actual width

    for ( ; value ; value >>= 1 ) {
        cnt += value & 1U;    // avoids a branch
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Note the width is passed to the function.

On architectures with < 32 bits (PIC, AVR, MSP430, etc.) specialized versions will gain much better results than a single version.