# How to deal with large numbers which cannot be store by int in c

Tags: c, floating-point, modulus

I am trying to do modulus operator on number upto 10^18. i cannot store this numbers in int and if i take it float then i cannot apply modulus operator so how can i do it.

I searched it but didn't find my answer.

I found one method to typecast but it cannot solve my problem and other is to use array.

So , there is only way to use array.

Comment: You don't show the calculation, but it can be posssible to do the modulus on its steps, so it never gets large.

Comment: If you're using the C99 standard or later, you can use the [long long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) type, which is at least 64 bits, and will hold 10^18.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring 64-bit variables in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451101/declaring-64-bit-variables-in-c)

Comment: Here is a list from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multiple_precision_arithmetic_libraries but it doesn't include all of them - there are a bunch more.  See: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=c%2B%2B+arbitrary+precision

Comment: You have kind of modulus operations on floating point see for example http://linux.die.net/man/3/remainder - it's just that 10^18 takes about 60 bits of data, a bit too much for IEEE double precision

Answer (score 3):

Use a `long long int` which ranges from −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. For unsigned values you can use `unsigned long long int`, which ranges from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Here are your choices

```
long long
long long int
signed long long
signed long long int
unsigned long long
unsigned long long int
```

Comment: yeah it's more like it depends on the platform, and the edited version by user3386109 is correct.

Comment: the int is optional so long long is equal to long long int, but I suggest using long long int it's clearer for non C or new C programmers.

Answer (score 0):

For long number you can use **unsigned long long int or long long int**
If this not working for you than you can use filing for storing values.

Comment: "Use filing for storing values"?